# JavaScript await asynchronous code execution in While loop

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

In a react component, I'm trying to fetch some data from an S3 bucket. S3 bucket have data in two folders `a` and `b`. Since there might be lot of keys in each folder, I'm making multiple calls in a while loop to get all the keys in each folder.

But the while loop is not exiting, even when **isTruncated** variable is set to false.

Somehow isTruncated seems to be true and `await this.getBuilds(prefix, marker);` inside `fetchKeys` is not waiting for the promise to be resolved.

```js
export default class Home extends Component {

  async componentWillMount() {
    await this.getAllBuilds(this.state.selectedApp);
  }

  fetchKeys = async prefix => {
    let buildsArr = [];
    let marker= '';
    let isTruncated = true;
    while (isTruncated) {
      const builds = await this.getBuilds(prefix, marker);
      if (builds.ListBucketResult.Contents) {
          builds.ListBucketResult.Contents.forEach(item => {
            buildsArr.push({'Key':item.Key, 'LastModified': item.LastModified});
          });
      }
      isTruncated = builds.ListBucketResult.IsTruncated;
      console.log('isTruncated :: '+ isTruncated);
      if (isTruncated) {
          marker = builds.ListBucketResult.Contents.slice(-1)[0].Key;
      }
    }
    return buildsArr;
  }

  getAllBuilds = async app => {
    const buildsPath = BUILDS_DIR[app];
    let betaBuilds = [];
    let alphaBuilds = [];
    try {
      alphaBuilds = await this.fetchKeys(`${buildsPath}/a/`);
      betaBuilds = await this.fetchKeys(`${buildsPath}/b/`);
      console.log('Alpha : ' + alphaBuilds);
      console.log('Beta : '+ betaBuilds);
    } catch(err){
      console.error(err);
    }
    
    this.setState({
      contentA: alphaBuilds,
      contentB: betaBuilds,
    });
  }

  async getBuilds(prefix, marker) {
    let uri = `/?list-type=1`;
    if (prefix) {
      uri += `&prefix=${prefix}`
    }
    if (marker) {
      uri += `&marker=${marker}`
    }
    console.log('URI is : '+ uri);
    
    const response = await get(uri,
            { baseURL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name",});
    const iosXml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
            response.data,
            'text/xml',
          );
    const iosJson = parseXml(iosXml);
    return Promise.resolve(iosJson);;      
  }

}
```

Comment: Aside: you only need one of `async` and `Promise.resolve` (e.g. `getBuilds`). Async functions will automatically wrap the return in a Promise if needed.

Comment: What is your output logs? would you please provide them?